# Visual Studio emulator for Android stuck at "OS is starting...", only on API Level 23 / Android 6

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

Since I read the news about Xamarin now being "free", I immediately installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and the Android tooling (NDKs, SDKs for 19-23, Visual Studio Emulator for Android dated January 2016) to start working on an Android application.

Excited I launched the emulator from `Tools -> Visual Studio Emulator for Android` and installed the profile that is the best match for my own phone. Since my phone is on Android 6, I decided to get a profile for API Level 23 / Android 6.

Since I had already enabled Hyper-V a few months ago, the installation for the profile only had to add me to the Administrators group and create 2 network adapters.

So far, so good.

Upon starting the emulator, it would stay at "OS is starting...". I figured I'd wait a while. I figured I'd wait a while longer too. After that, I gave up the possibility of it going to work and started investigating.

I also tried other profiles, a few others from API Level 23, one from 22 and one from 19. Only the ones from API Level 23 did not work.

The following steps are what I came up with so far by Googling etc. I tried them in all sorts of combinations:

- Rebooting
- Disabling / enabling Hyper-V
- Removing vEthernet adapters (through the Hyper-V Manager).
- Running XDECleanup
- Allowing XDE through my Windows Firewall as application (incoming)
- Restoring the emulator software in `Programs and Features`
- Enabling / disabling "Processor Compatibility" in Hyper-V Manager.

This is the data I've gathered so far:

- A screenshot of the error message that the emulator gives after waiting a long time (10 - 15 minutes, maybe a little longer)

[image: 1]

- A screenshot of the last part of the log when being connected to the Android 6 VM:

[image: 1]

- A screenshot of the last part of the log of a working VM (this one's from an Android 4.4 VM):

[image: 2]

Comment: I can confirm this issue. The stock Android images worked (KitKat 4.4) - 5.0, 5.1.1's work fine as well. But none of the API23 (Marshmallow 6.0) profiles work. I also checked the C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices folder to make sure the .vhd were getting deleted.

Answer (score 15):

Responses I've got so far from Microsoft:

-Those errors are normal
-And the only step I've tryed which they told me to, and I don't see here, it's this one:

[On Hyper-V Manager, check the option for compatibility under CPU section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyF0m.jpg)

Besides from this, just make sure that on Hyper-V you get only 2 switches, the one you use to connect to the internet and the one that the VS Emulator for Android creates, I haven't got any results, but if you try, maybe you will.

Comment: I have tried this today and it has not resolved the issue. I'm pretty sure I tried it before but forgot to mention it in my question. I've also updated the question.

Comment: To elaborate more on this issue, I've changed my pc for personal reasons, and now I'm able to run every VS Android Emulator, including the API 23 ones, I never got the 23 working with my old computer, even though the hardware should have been more than enough, anyway, I think there is a hardware compatibility issue I think, but that's just a hypothesis of mine.

Comment: @JesúCastillo by any chance, did you upgrade ram size in the new machine?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle I'm not working with this stack anymore, but I didn't at the time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was mucking around with the VS emulator's virtual switches and had the network adapters in the wrong order.

After I moved the `Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch` (Created when first running the VS Emulator) to the first `Network Adapter slot` in my settings, the emulator started up just fine. Apparently, order matters.

[image]

Comment: This work for me after a year of giving up to use real device. It work wonderfully way back until i did a windows driver update and it all went sour.

Order seems to matter, in my case i deleted others leaving only the Windows Phone one

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but got mine to work after trying a lot of things from different threads.

In the end I think this did the trick for me:

- I added "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe" as an exception in the firewall.
- (i also switched of the firewall, but was probably unnecessary)
- Temporarly disabled the WiFi device
- Uninstalled VirtualBox
- Removed all Virtual Switches in Hyper-V
- Executed XdeCleanup.exe
- Started the emulator again and it started up successfully!

Swiched of the emulator and enabled Firewall, Wifi device.
The emulator still starts successfully every time!

Thanks to all for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xamarin, it's recommended that you use [Xamarin Player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player). It's not Xamarin exclusive, it's just a much faster Android emulator. I use Android Studio, and the Xamarin Player is still faster on boot and launch than the default. This is just my recommendation to you, I have no clue how to fix your Visual Studio emulator, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm fairly certain the Visual Studio Emulator for Android serves the same purpose. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It serves the same purpose, but I don't believe that it uses hyper-v, or any of the same resources as the current emulator. Just a guess that the conflicts that you're having now would not appear in Xamarin Player.

Comment: These errors occur when you just launch the emulator with the API 23 images. No Visual Studio or Xamarin involved.

Comment: Unless you like to avoid the trouble to reboot if you are going to develop for any Hyper-V emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've played a lot with this and realized that I have had manually configured paging file on Windows. After restoring it to default all worked perfectly without messing with the virtual switches or adapters.

Just make sure that you have all Windows memory etc. settings set to default.

Regards, Mladen

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the ***system image was missing*** for the emulator.
When I opened the **android virtual device manager** it had an *exclamation mark* next to actions(i had to download the system image via the **download link**).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. The solution for me was:

1. Uninstall all emulators in the Visual Studio Emulator for Android
2. Check in Hyper-V-Manager if there also no instances
3. Unistall Visual Studio Emulator for Android
4. Run xdecleanup.exe (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE*)
5. Uninstall Hyper-V from Windows features
6. Removed virtual ethernet adapters through uninstalling in `Device Manager`
   (be sure to display disabled devices too)
7. Install Hyper-V from Windows features
8. Install Visual Studo Emulator for Android again
9. Download and install your emulator/profile
10. Run the emulator and have fun :-)

It seems there was a problem with the virtual switches and Hyper-V. The correct settings for the adapter looks like these:

**Hyper-V-Manager:**

[image: Virtual Switch 1]
[image: Virtual Switch 2]

**Device Manager:**

[image: Device Manager Ethernet adapters]

**Network adapter:**

[image: Windows network adapter]
*Ethernet:*
[image: Main ethernet is the Hyper-V switch]
*vEthernet (Virtueller Switch: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM #2):*
[image: Hyper-V ethernet 1]
*vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch):*
[image: Hyper-V ethernet 2]

**Emulator network settings:**

[image: Emulator Internal Network Adapter]
[image: Emulator External Network Adapter]